# Why a variable declared in a class globally is not visible/accsible in same class method?

Tags: c#

i made a class in app code folder in visual studio 2010. when i declared any variable outside of a method(globally), it can't be visible in that method. I am new in asp.net, may be i make any mistake but i can't catch that. So i need some help. my code is as follow...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class Class2
{

public Class2()

    {
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
    }

int i;

public static void calculate(string)
{
    // here want that variable but i can't get it in intelliscence.  
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That method is `static`.

You cannot access an instance member from a `static` method. That doesn't make sense.

Think of `static` as "global to every possible instance of the class". Your `int i` variable means "global.. to a single instance of the class". When you think of it like that, it makes sense that you can't access a variable that is "global to a single instance" from a method that is "global to every instance".

Hopefully that makes sense? (probably needs to be re-phrased.. I was just trying to make it easier to understand)

Comment: thanx, so what should i do to access the variables in static method.

Comment: You can't. You can only access them through an instance of the class. You _could_ `new` up an instance of your class from within the method.. or, you could just remove `static` from the method.

Comment: If you want your method to be `static`, you can pass your instance variables to it when you call it. Or you could simply drop the `static` from the method so it runs in the scope of the instance, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A `static` method can only access static members.

Static methods cannot access non-static class level members. Instance methods can access static members, but must be called through an instantiated object.

Answer (score 0):

A static method cannot access non static members. To use non static members, create an object of the class and then use the get/set methods.

Answer (score 0):

A **static** method can only access **static** data members. You should use **static** variable to work in **static** method.